# How to get state of _app.js in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have initiated a state in `_app.js` using Next.js.
I would like to use this state in the `index.js` file. 
How can I access it?

This is my `_app.js` code:

```
import React from 'react';
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

export default class MyApp extends App {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currencyType: {
        name: 'Ether',
        price: 1,
      },
      ethPriceUsd: 1,
    };
  }

  static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {};
    let ethPriceUsd;

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/ethereum/`)
        .then((result) => result.json())
        .then((data) => {
          ethPriceUsd = parseFloat(data.market_data.current_price.usd).toFixed(
            2
          );
        });
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    return { pageProps, ethPriceUsd };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const ethPriceUsd = this.props.ethPriceUsd;
    this.setState({ ethPriceUsd });
  }

  onCurrencyTypeChange(currencyTypeValue) {
    let currencyType = {};
    //Value comes from Header.js where Ether is 0 and USD is 1
    if (currencyTypeValue) {
      currencyType = {
        name: 'USD',
        price: this.state.ethPriceUsd,
      };
    } else {
      currencyType = {
        name: 'Ether',
        price: 1,
      };
    }
    alert('We pass argument from Child to Parent: ' + currencyType.price);
    this.setState({ currencyType });
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Layout changeCurrencyType={this.onCurrencyTypeChange.bind(this)}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

A lot of it is irrelevant (Like passing the data to the Layout etc...). All I want to do is use this state in my `index.js`.

Comment: You can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: The _app,js already uses context internally

Comment: Just for reminder, the `Container` in `_app` has been deprecated and should be removed. [**App Container Deprecated**](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/errors/app-container-deprecated.md)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

let's say you have this code in `_app.js`.

```
import React from 'react'
import App, { Container } from 'next/app'

export default class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return { pageProps }
  }

  state = {
    name: "Morgan",
  }

  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

    return (
      <Container>
        <Component {...pageProps} {...this.state}/>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Please notice the `state` and `<Component {...pageProps} {...this.state}/>`

### Solution 1:

Now, let's see how can we use it in `index.js` or *any other pages*

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Index extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>My name is {this.props.name}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You can use them as **props** like this `this.props.name`

### Solution 2:

Populate state in the `index.js` from `props` and then access it from `state`

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Index extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state ={
           name: this.props.name
       }
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>My name is {this.state.name}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You can use them as **props** like this `this.state.name`

Comment: And how to access them inside index getInitialProps?

Comment: They are in props for all pages

Comment: Using solution 1, are there any downsides for sending the full _app state to each of it's children? Let's say I have more than 10 variables in state, most rendered pages will only need 2 or 3, but they receive the rest of the 10 too. Is this (significantly) problematic in any way?

Comment: it really depends.. If you think about redux, it does the same thing(kind of). Most of the time it is safe and ok to share you data between your component.(as I said, most of the time). However it depends on the data...

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same things when index.js is a functional component, hence using hooks?